# Virtual destructor makes it necessary to export the interface on VS2017

Tags: c++, linker-errors, destructor, dllexport

I have a C++ interface, let's call it `IX` with a few methods:

```
class IX
{
public:
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual void bar() = 0;
}
```

this interface is located inside a library (dll), but considering the fact that it includes no implementation, it has not been exported.

But, If I want to add a virtual destructor to this interface, like below, then the VS2017 linker complains about the implementation of the destructor that cannot be found:

```
class IX
{
public:
   virtual ~IX() = 0;
   virtual void foo() = 0;
   virtual void bar() = 0;
}
```

The linker error:

```
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl IX::~IX(void)" (??1IX@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl B::~B(void)" (??1B@@UEAA@XZ)    test_project
```

One solution could be to export the interface (and potentially put `=default` implementation for the dtor). But my Q is why adding a virtual destructor can lead to such kind of linker error?

Comment: Works [here](https://godbolt.org/z/5YjxaWWcn). Can you provide [MRE]

Comment: @NutCracker Yes, I know that within a single file it works fine. But, as I have mentioned, the interface should be defined inside a dll and be used outside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making something pure virtual doesn't mean it doesn't have an implementation. Its totally legal (and sometimes useful) to have an implementation of a pure virtual function.

In the case of `foo() = 0;` you dont explicitly call `IX::foo()`  anywhere, so not having an implementation is ok. It cant be implicitly called as it'll always be overridden.

Destructors are different. They will always be implicitly called by the parents destructor in a chain. So you need an implementation of the destructor *even if its pure virtual*.